# SQL Server VS2019 Dotnet updates the database but it is not in the SQL Server Explorer window

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

I am creating my first SQL type database in Visual Studio using NET 3.1. I successfully created the initial create migration files. When I build the database it claims it was built, but I cannot find it. Shouldn't it show up in the SQL Server Explorer window in VS2019?

```
PM> dotnet ef database update --context StoreContext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Done.
```

Comment: Did you refresh?

Comment: That was it!  It is there after refresh. Thanks.